# How to sum 2 variables and store it into one variable

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a mainreport containing 2 different subreports.

I have a variable sum from a subreport1 for example 10(type Integer)

I have another variable sum from another subreport2 for example 2(type Integer)

I have **successfully retreived the 2 variables from each of the subreports**
now I want to create a variable in my mainreport that sums up the 2 variables

so now in my mainreport I have 3 variables

the first variable is called VAR1 and it came  from subreport 1

```
Name                       VAR1
Variable Class             java.lang.Integer
Reset type                 Report
initial Value Expression   0
```

the second variable is called VAR2 and it came  from subreport 2

```
Name                       VAR2
Variable Class             java.lang.Integer
Reset type                 Report
initial Value Expression   0
```

the last variable is called SUM

```
Name                       SUM
Variable Class             java.lang.Integer
Reset type                 Report
variable expression        new Integer($V{VAR1}.intValue() + $V{VAR2}.intValue() )
initial Value Expression   0
```

The SUM variable is NULL when i preview the pdf , VAR1 and VAR2 are Integer values but the SUM variable is always NULL

could it be that the SUM was evaluated before VAR1 and VAR2?

what is my problem?

Comment: This depends of the band in which your SUM variable is used. Also, did you display the values of VAR1 and VAR2 for testing purposes in the report?

Comment: I have 3 detail bands in my mainreport, the 1st detail band contains my 1st subreport , the 2nd detail band contains the 2nd subreport, the 3rd detail band contains the 3 variables VAR1 , VAR2 and SUM, and yes my VAR1 and VAR2 are displayed for testing purposes. In the end I only want the SUM displayed in the 3rd detail band but it is null and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you try changing the `Evaluation Time` of the SUM variable, maybe to "Now"? Also, have you tried using another band like `Summary` or a `Group Footer`?

Comment: I set the Evaluation Time of the SUM variable to "now" (before it was report) and I also placed it in the summary band, still null

Comment: one thing to point out is that VAR1 and VAR2 displayed just fine, they are the numbers that I expected , but I'm stuck because I can't get the SUM variable to represent the sum of those two variables...

Comment: I suspect something goes wrong with the calculation part. Have you tried the expression `$V{VAR1} + $V{VAR2}`? Put that into a text field and see if the calculation works in the first place.

Comment: I have tried the expression $V{VAR1} + $V{VAR2} and put it in a text field, the result IS ACTUALLY THE SUM of VAR1 and VAR2, but the SUM value is still null even when I changed the expression. Since the text field can represent the sum of VAR1 and VAR2 , why can't the "variable" SUM? I guess I'll use the text field to represent the sum of VAR1 and VAR2 for now since it works.....thanks...kinda solved my issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, using variables with values returned from subreports to calculate other variables does not work because "regular" variable values are computed before the subreports render and return values.

If you only need to sum the returned values, one thing that you can do is to return the value from the two subreports into the same variable, using calculation="Sum" for the return value.  That is return val1 from the first subreport to VAR1 and the same val1 to SUM with calculation="Sum", and return val2 from the second subreport to VAR1 and to SUM with calculation="Sum".

Note that calculation="Sum" is for the return value and not the variable; variables that are used for return values would typically need to have calculation="System".

Comment: Thanks for that, it helped me a lot!