# JasperSoft Studio - Sum a variable in a Report from a repeat Subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I had been looking through JasperReports Api and StackOverflow and I had see that I need to declare a variable and pass the value from the subreport for each subreport I have even if they are the same.

I´m refactoring and old report. In this case I have one subreport per day of the week and they return the same values. Because I need to calculate the total in the main. I have 4 diferents times to calculate per report. So I must have 4 x 5/7 variables in the main. And I´m looking for a way to have only 1 return variable name for all of them.

Is this possible ?

This is how the time is calculated for administrative leaves:

> (I´m going to change this to a minute parameter and calculate with a
>   format in the textfield instead of this. And do the sum in a variable,
>   but this is what I have pre-refactor)

```
<band height="8">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="325" y="3" width="5" height="5" uuid="2200e4dc-97da-4be9-bd0d-8e1bb6f2a548"/>
                <subreportParameter name="CarerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Employee_Id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DayCalculated">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date($P{StartDate}.getTime() + 48*60*60*1000)]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day_3"/>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_Cero" toVariable="Global_Time_Cero_3"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["administrativeLeaves_in_planning10.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="3" width="5" height="5" uuid="f7c041f5-0fb7-4340-9004-abb40a40d72b"/>
                <subreportParameter name="CarerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Employee_Id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DayCalculated">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{StartDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day_1"/>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_Cero" toVariable="Global_Time_Cero_1"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["administrativeLeaves_in_planning10.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="487" y="3" width="5" height="5" uuid="7582ab3d-165b-4c20-b0ec-8049096a1287"/>
                <subreportParameter name="CarerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Employee_Id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DayCalculated">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date($P{StartDate}.getTime() + 72*60*60*1000)]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day_4"/>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_Cero" toVariable="Global_Time_Cero_4"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["administrativeLeaves_in_planning10.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="164" y="3" width="5" height="5" uuid="f61b9c11-cd2e-4d0b-be64-2964ee8d2aaf"/>
                <subreportParameter name="CarerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Employee_Id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DayCalculated">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date($P{StartDate}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day_2"/>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_Cero" toVariable="Global_Time_Cero_2"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["administrativeLeaves_in_planning10.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="649" y="3" width="5" height="5" uuid="359cbbca-c469-4c35-9e44-68c286a953a9"/>
                <subreportParameter name="CarerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Employee_Id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DayCalculated">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date($P{StartDate}.getTime() + 96*60*60*1000)]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day_5"/>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_Cero" toVariable="Global_Time_Cero_5"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["administrativeLeaves_in_planning10.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
```

And then is all added (I know it's one of the worst code I've seen)  :

```
(($V{Global_Time_in_Day_1} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_2} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_3} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_4} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_5} )%60) < 10
?
(($V{Global_Time_in_Day_1} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_2} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_3} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_4} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_5} )/60)
+":0"+
(($V{Global_Time_in_Day_1} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_2} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_3} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_4} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_5} )%60)+" h"
:
(($V{Global_Time_in_Day_1} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_2} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_3} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_4} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_5} )/60)
+":"+
(($V{Global_Time_in_Day_1} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_2} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_3} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_4} +
$V{Global_Time_in_Day_5} )%60)+" h"
```

And What I want to do is `<returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day"/>` to the same variable in the Main and get the summatory instead of having one `Global_Time_in_Day_X` per subreport in the main.

**"Bibliography"**

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html

[How to sum 2 variables and store it into one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382438/how-to-sum-2-variables-and-store-it-into-one-variable)

Comment: You can sum several return values into a single variable by using a calculation for the return value, as in <returnValue subreportVariable=".." toVariable="TravelTimeMo" calculation="Sum"/>.  You can have several return values using the same TravelTimeMo destination variable.

Comment: @dada67 Yes but that is not exactly what I mean. I mean to have 2 subreports with **toVariable="TravelTimeMo"** and sum then only for returning a variable with the same name.

Comment: I don't understand the case, can you give a concrete example or more details?

Comment: @dada67 Edit to give the concrete example

Comment: Are you saying that having <returnValue subreportVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" toVariable="Global_Time_in_Day" calculation="Sum"/> in all 5 subreports (instead of Global_Time_in_Day_X) wouldn't work?